# UNRAID / Cloudflare Tunnel with Docker Container running File Browser gives error 502 bad gateway

Tags: docker, cloudflare, tunnel, bad-gateway, http-status-code-502

I am new to cloudflare tunnels and I am right now trying to reach my services at home from anywhere.
An VPN is no option because my internet provider gives me a private IP adress.

I know how to set up an tunnel connection. An docker container running with Emby works fine and is with cloudflare tunnels reachable from the internet. (see image) [image: cloudflare emby setup]

But with the same settings and the Docker container File Browser (https://hub.docker.com/r/filebrowser/filebrowser) i get the error 502 bad gateway.

Does anybody knows how to fix the problem?

I already tried to use other services and the most services did work, but File Browser and Nextcloud wont.

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that Cloudflare Docker / Filebrowser Docker aren't communicating because by default Filebrowser runs on a different IP subnet than default installs of other Docker containers. You are getting Emby and other services to work because they are defaulted to the same IP as the Cloudflare docker - let's call that `192.168.1.A:{unique port per service}`.

When you install the Filebrowser docker with default values, it puts in on `192.168.1.B:80`.
So, when you set up the tunnel on the Cloudflare website, it can't find the Filebrowser because it isn't on the same IP as the Cloudflare Docker.

To fix this, change the FileBrowser Docker container to these settings:

```
WebUI: http://[IP]:[PORT:80]
Network Type: Bridge (defaults to br0)
```

Then, add a port:

```
Name: whatever you want
Container Port: 80
Host Port: whatever you want (ex.8088)
```

Save and start the Docker and it should now have the same IP as your Cloudflare / Emby / other containers. In your tunnel settings in your Cloudflare account just paste the new FileBrowser IP in the URL box from your screenshot: `192.168.1.A:8080`.